# Why wouldn’t the government reform the secret service?

Tags: internal-consistency, military

So, in my world, nuclear war happened, and the US has been forced to retreat into underground bases and shelters, were they stay for the next 90 years.

During their time underground, they grow increasingly Nazi-esque. Xenophobia, fascism, and so on. They still have the presidential office, along with the secret service, who are armed with the most advanced weapons the Bunker can give. But, the Secret Servicemen often, politically meddle, killing of new presidents and candidates, giving “impeachment” a new meaning.

My question is, after all of this, why would the citizens of the Bunker not reform the Secret Service?

Comment: You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868), which isn't a good fit for our site.  Worldbuilding (on-topic) is about systems and rules.  Storybuilding (off-topic) is about circumstances.  If you remove 100% of the story from your question and have no question left, the question is too story-based.  (And even if you disagree with that assessment, the question is [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).)

Comment: @JBH: Is their a story-building stack exchange?

Comment: @RobertPaul No, you're expected to do that bit on your own.  I'm fond of analyzing problems like this with trees:  Reform isn't happening either because the citizens can't, or because they don't want to.  If they don't want to, it's because they are benefiting, or because they are being deceived.  If they are being deceived, it's by the secret service, or a third party, or by happy coincidence... etc, etc, until you start digging into specific ideas and finding ones that work.

Comment: Because they are armed? Not wanting to get killed is perfectly valid reason not to annoy people with weapons.

Comment: No, regrettably there isn't.  [writing.se] is as close as it gets, but they're more focused on being a good writer than they are what you're writing, and as I recall, simple idea-generation questions are off-topic for them.  We've tossed around the idea of proposing a storybuilding.SE site on [area51.se], but the concept violates key philosophies of Stack Exchange (most notably, that questions should be objective following the one-specific-question/one-best-answer rule).  So, in a nutshell.  No.

Comment: First you say that the political regime becomes more and more authoritarian; you actually say "Nazi-esque", but I assume you meant authoritarian. Then you ask why don't the *citizens* reform something. *Because they live under an authoritarian regime*, that's why. It's like asking why didn't the citizens of the Soviet Union reform the KGB. And finally, you are asking the community to invent a major plot point for your story; you may want to notice that user contributions on this site are licensed [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)...

Answer (score 1):

All the time, they have been operating under emergency conditions. Martial law, probably. Having a [Pretorian Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praetorian_Guard) for several generations has historical precedent. So why not here?

So at first it is the emergency which forced them into the bunkers, and then it is the conditions of living in a very fragile ecosystem.

- It is dangerous out there. Everybody has to pitch in to survive. Don't rock the boat. What are you, a [Commie Mutant Traitor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TabletopGame/Paranoia)?
- How much of the supreme court made it into the bunker? Can they challenge the President and **his goons** under these conditions? What happens between the President and his staff behind closed doors is never proven ...
- No free press, right? I mean, the tech level is too early for an internet/intranet and paper will be seriously rationed. Official proclamations on official message boards only.
- People in power could claim that **no reform at all** is possible because legitimate State legislatures would be needed to touch the [25th amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution). This may or may not be true, see above for the court.

It could all come apart, as it did in the [Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perestroika), [East Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Wende), or [Romania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_Revolution). Or it could keep on for generations, as in [North Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea).